# Syntax highlighting in .vim for python segments files on windows

Tags: windows, vim, python

I use python a lot in my vimrc. On my linux machine it correctly highlights segments of code between

```
func! VIMSCRIPT_FUNC_WITH_PYTHON()

python << endpython
import vim
vim.command('%s/foo/bar/g')  # some python code inside vimscript
endpython

endfu
```

However on my windows machines these python snippets have no highlighting. I tried looking for any difference in the .vim syntax files, but nothing jumped out at me. Google has produced nothing useful. Any idea how to get python code embedded in .vimrc files to have correct syntax highlighting?

Comment: Is it the same vim config on both machines, is it the same version?

Comment: Is your Vim on Windows compiled with Python support, and do you have the right version of Python installed for Vim to interact with (i.e. does `:echo has('python')` show 1)?